# TextArea control - what data structure to use and how to get line by line

Tags: java, sorting, textarea

What data structure do I use to get the text from a TextArea Javax control in order  to use the text line by line elsewhere?

Comment: Is this a JavaScript question? Are you referring to a JTextArea?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: So I'm using a popup combobox to allow the user to select items from a list and then add each to the TextArea. I want to get each line the user added and then be able to sort the text alphabetically. For example: User adds Bannana, Apple, Carrot to the text area, I want to be able to grab that and then sort it to be Apple,Bannana, Carrot .

Comment: @Fxguy1 you haven't answered my question. Is this related to JavaScript?

Comment: Sorry, no it's in a java application I'm trying to build. I'm sorry if I'm not clear, I'm pretty much entirely self taught when it comes to Java.

Comment: @Fxguy1 thanks. Now it is more clear. Next time remember to add all the appropriate tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, you're talking about a JavaFX control. The [TextArea](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextArea.html) control.
You can get the contained text via

```
final String text = textArea.getText();
```

You can then split the `String` by the system line separator

```
final String[] lines = text.split(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
```

You can then order it via

```
Arrays.sort(lines);
```

Comment: Thank you! Thank you! I have no idea what I was doing wrong but your code worked. I was WAY over complicating things. So this splits the lines into a String Array correct?

Comment: @Fxguy1 exactly.

Comment: Ok, one last question. How can I compare if one String Array contains an element from another? Would that be boolean Found = StringArray1.contains(StringArray2)?

Comment: @Fxguy1 this is more suited for a List<String>. See the List#retainAll method. You can convert the String arrays to two List<String> and then apply retainAll to the first one. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#retainAll(java.util.Collection)

Comment: Ok. So to be able to sort and display them alphabetically keep them in the String Array but for compares convert them to String Lists is that correct?

Comment: @Fxguy1 Yes. Anyway I'd always immediatly convert the String array to a List<String>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189016/discussion-between-fxguy1-and-lppedd).

Answer (score 0):

As stated by LppEdd, the best way to do this is to create a String variable to hold the entire text as so:

```
final String text = textArea.getText();
```

You can then split the String by the system line separator (or whatever character you wish) in my case it was "\n" :

```
final String[] lines = text.split("\n");
```

At this point you can sort and store into another data structure such as a TreeMap.